# How to replace special character with Hexadecimal value in WSO2 FTP?

Tags: wso2-esb

In WSO2 documentation of "Configuring  File Inbound Protocol for FTP, SFTP and FILE Connections", it is told that "If the password contains special characters, these characters will need to be replaced with their hexadecimal representation". Say my URL looks like this : - ftp://admin:pass@localhost/orders

The value for my password is say GGG#12@12345. How will I write my password by replacing special characters in password.

Comment: any luck trying the solution below?

Answer (score 2):

Special characters (like @ in username, see example below) have to be encoded using %XX syntax, where XX is hexadecimal UTF-8 code.

```
Char     Hex Code
-------  --------
[space]    %20
   "       %22
   #       %23
   $       %24
   %       %25
   &       %26
   '       %27
   (       %28
   )       %29
   *       %2A
   +       %2B
   ,       %2C
   -       %2D
   .       %2E
   /       %2F
   :       %3A
   ;       %3B
   <       %3C
   =       %3D
   >       %3E
   ?       %3F
   @       %40
   \       %5C
   ^       %5E
   `       %60
   |       %7C
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Could you please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark so people can see that this issue is resolved and focus on the other, still open issues? Thanks!